# Powershell - Exception raised via "Validation" Attributes on functions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a function like this in Powershell. When the user passes a null string for any of the parameters, powershell validates and raises exception. How do I handle such exceptions ?

```
function CheckADUser()
{
    param(
            [ValidateLength(1,256)]
            [string]$domainName, 
            [ValidateLength(1,256)]
            [string]$username, 
            [ValidateLength(1,256)]
            [string]$password)
    Process{
    $fullyQualifiedUser = $domainName+"\"+$username
    $domain = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("", $fullyQualifiedUser, $password)
    return $domain.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the exception using a try/catch block:

```
try {
  checkaduser $null $null $null
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException] {
  # exception handling code
}
```